# Weird output from printing out the contents of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, output

I'm currently pushing in the values to an array from std_input but am not getting anywhere near the right point, for some of the points of the 2d array.

Feeding it the input A={0,1,...,8,9} from a file and my own input should yield the 2d arr
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9

but yields
1 2 4
4 5 7
7 8 9

```
//Constructor for a user input holding array.

 Matrix::Matrix(char n){
  int i; int j;
  int input;
  cout << "Begin input of the numbers in the needed vector." <<endl;
  for(i=0;i <3; i++){
    for(j=0; j<3; j++){
      cin >> input;      
      arr_3x3[i][j] = input;
      cout << input <<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong at this point.
The print function is as follows, and works for all the other array markers:

```
void Matrix::print_arr(){
  int i; int j;
  for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    for(j=0; j<3; j++){
      cout << arr_3x3[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  cout << endl <<endl;
}
```

Comment: how is `arr_9x9` declared?

Comment: You do not need to declare all local variables at the top of a function; this was only required in <= C90, never in C++. Limiting the scope of variables (by introducing them later, e.g. within the for-init-statement) often makes the code easier to understand and prevents certain bugs.

Comment: Also don't print out the number you just entered. It makes for a messy input process.

Comment: Also, with `int arr_9x9[9][9]` (or `[3][3]`) this works fine for me. Also note that you're using the array as a 3x3, not a 9x9.

Comment: I declared it as just a private: int arr3x3[2][2]     point for the needed values, sorry about the 9x9 miscount on my part renamed it. It works perfectly fine when I am attempting to print out either an empty '0' for all values or a diagonal array, which I implemented roughly the same way, but this is not pushing out the right points. I also placed the print statement to check the value in input itself due to the continued wrong point. SOrry for the long comment, I'm new at this.

Comment: The bounds provided in an array declaration are not the maximum indices, but the number of elements. I.e. you have declared an array of 4 elements (2x2). This leads to an out-of-bounds access in your loops.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for that, first time implementing an array in C++ for some weird reason I was under the impression that it counted the numbers 0,1,2 as I do in the loops. Kind of feel dumb-ish right now but gotta relearn some things.

Comment: Hm? For an `array[x]` one uses a loop `for (i=0; i<x; i++)`. The array starts at 0 and continues up to (but not including) `x`, and so does the loop.

Comment: @Jongware The array is declared as `int arr3x3[2][2]` and the loops use `i < 3` and `j < 3`.

Comment: @dyp, yeah I noticed that too. Now I am confused about what's so confusing for the OP.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, but it was just a minor misreading on my part in regards to the arrays size, I was thinking in the point of, as was said by dyp and @jongware stated going off of the indices instead of actual needed size of the given array.